# Create test and development copy of a production site

Tags: migrations

I have a Drupal8 site on my hosting account. I created a copy from the database; 
I create a copy of the code.

Both the copies I used should be a copy of my production site. I imported the SQL into a new database. I changed the settings of the copied Drupal code to point to my new database.

When I go to the browser and look at local install I can only get to the install page.

Can anyone please point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with your settings.php file.

- Check if the name is correct.
- Check if the database is set correctly.
- Try to access in command Line to the database.
- Check rights of your files.
- Try to clear the cache with drush cr.

Comment: Perfectly right, working nicely